# Java API for Downloading/Reading data from Sharepoint excel

Tags: java, sharepoint

I have a sharepoint URL with access for anyone with the URL. When I access the Sharepoint URL with my browser, a login screen pops up and once we proceed with the SSO login screen, the excel is downloaded onto my machine. I'm trying to achieve the same using REST APIs.

Here's what I've tried.

```
    RestTemplate template =  new RestTemplate();
    //Getting 403 Here.
    byte[] imageBytes = template.getForObject("https://sharepointhost/Documents/Document_Name.xlsx", byte[].class);
    InputStream targetStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageBytes);
    Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(targetStream);
```

Is there a way I can pass my credentials so as to programmatically download and access the file?

Comment: Old but related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25000055/how-to-authenticate-in-sharepoint-2010-using-username-password-in-java Also see here on authentication: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-rest-endpoints

Comment: It didn't work though. hence looking for another way

Comment: Please edit your question to show us how you are trying to authenticate your credentials with sharepoint currently. The second link in my previous comment should have all the details you need.